# How to create 24 bit unsigned integer in C

Tags: c, struct, printf, typedef

I am working on an embedded application where RAM is extremely tight.
For this purpose I need to create a 24 bit unsigned integer data type.  I am doing this using a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t v : 24;
} uint24_t;
```

However when I interrogate the size of a variable of this type, it returns "4", i.e.:

```
    uint24_t x;
    x.v = 0;
    printf("Size = %u", sizeof(x));
```

Is there a way I can force this variable to have 3 bytes?

Initially I thought it was because it is forcing datatypes to be word aligned, but I can for example do this:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t blah[3];
} mytype;
```

And in that case the size comes out at 3.

Comment: I am not sure this will save you RAM. CPU is most probably 32bit and so each address of a variable will typically still be 4-byte aligned.

Comment: Not if it is an array of 24 bit variables, right?

Comment: If you want an array of them you can use `uint8_t` and figure out the indexing an d packing/unpacking yourself.

Comment: @bgarrood, array elements are laid out contiguously in memory, yes, so if you could create a 24-bit type then an array having that as its element type could not have all elements aligned on 32-bit boundaries.  This is a very good reason why your implementation might not provide a way to define 24-bit types.  But then again, it might.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could try to *ensure* that the structure only takes up the space you need, with something like:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct { uint8_t byt[3]; } UInt24;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

You *may* have to provide those compiler directives (like the `#pragma` lines above) to ensure there's no padding but this will *probably* be the default for a structure with only eight-bit fields<sup>(a)</sup>.

You would probably then have to pack/unpack real values to and from the structure, something like:

```
// Inline suggestion used to (hopefully) reduce overhead.

inline uint32_t unpack(UInt24 x) {
    uint32_t retVal = x.byt[0];
    retVal = retVal << 8 | x.byt[1];
    retVal = retVal << 8 | x.byt[2];
    return retVal;
}
                                      
inline UInt24 pack(uint32_t x) {
    UInt24 retVal;
    retVal.byt[0] = (x >> 16) & 0xff;
    retVal.byt[1] = (x >> 8) & 0xff;
    retVal.byt[2] = x & 0xff;
    return retVal;
}
```

Note that this gives you big-endian values regardless of your actual architecture. This won't matter if you're exclusively packing and unpacking yourself, but it *may* be an issue if you want to use the memory blocks elsewhere in a *specific* layout (in which case you can just change the pack/unpack code to use the desired format).

This method adds a little code to your system (and a probably minimal performance penalty) so you'll have to decide if that's worth the saving in data space used.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> For example, both `gcc 7.3` and `clang 6.0` show `3 6` for the following program, showing that there is no padding either within or following the structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct { uint8_t byt[3]; } UInt24;
int main() {
    UInt24 x, y[2];
    printf("%zd %zd\n", sizeof(x), sizeof(y));
    return 0;
}
```

However, that *is* just a sample so you may want to consider, in the interest of portable code, using something like `#pragma pack(1)`, or putting in code to catch environments where this may not be the case.

Comment: Even this does not ensure that type `uint24_t` consumes only four bytes.  The compiler is permitted to include padding in the structure layout, and it probably will do in this case.  There may be an extension available, to instruct the compiler not to do so.  In some implementations, such a thing might be spelled `#progma pack(1)` or similar.

Comment: @JohnBollinger since `uint8_t` is 1 byte aligned, so is `uint8t_[3]` and so is `uint24_t`. Since `uint24_t` is 1 byte aligned, the most obvious and common scenario is for `uint24_t` size to be indeed `3`

Comment: @John, the most likely case is that it won't pad but, since it *may,* I've added a note to that effect.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I'm unsure what your basis is for supposing that padding is unlikely.  There are widely-used implementations that have a default 4-byte or even larger alignment requirement for all structure types, and any such implementation will add trailing padding unless somehow instructed not to do.

Comment: @John, probably *the* most widely used is `gcc`, and the program snippet `uint24_t x, y[2]; printf("%zd %zd\n", sizeof(x), sizeof(y));` gives `3 6`, showing no padding within or after the structure. Ditto for `clang`. There may be others that don't pack that tight by default, which is why I took your suggestion to clarify it in the answer. I'll post details in the answer as well.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Citation? I'm not aware of any modern real-world implementationt that over-align structs.

Comment: This probably doesn't save much RAM since you get function call overhead + an uint32 on the stack. Rather, it gives much higher RAM peak usage compared to working with `uint32_t`. Stack depth is a major concern on systems where RAM is tight. You'd have to ensure that the functions get inlined, as a bare minimum.

Comment: @Lundin, my assumption was that the OP had a large array of these values and was wasting 25% when they were taking 32 bits each. A 24-bit structure woluld mitigate that and, yes, there is a cost, both in pack/unpack performance and in some extra code, users should decide on whether that's worth it. I didn't bother inlining since, to be honest, the `inline` *suggestion* is often rendered unnecessary by modern compilers that can work out how to best inline stuff. It's been a while since I've tried to out-guess the insanely-optimising compilers of late :-) I *will* add it as a suggestion however.

Comment: @R..: Good point, have renamed the type. For those interested, these types are specified as reserved in `C11 7.31 Future library directions - All external names described below are reserved no matter what headers are included by the program`in conjunction with `7.31.10 <stdint.h> Typedef names beginning with int or uint and ending with _t may be added to the types deﬁned in the <stdint.h> header`.

Comment: @paxdiablo There's a big chance this is for the infamous PIC, compiled with the even more infamous MPLAB, rather than with a modern compiler.

Comment: Shouldn't we take in consideration memory alignment in general if the aim is to save RAM? For instance if I declare three gloval variables as UInt24 varx, vary[2]; uint32_t varz; and then check the output.map file genrated with gcc -Xlinker -Map=output.map, I get varx aligned to 4 bytes inside the .bss sector. Same behaviour with the -Os option which optimizes in size.

Comment: @matteo, again it depends on the environment. I've offered only a way in which you *could* save memory, this may or may not work as is on *every* environment. I'd be interested in seeing your layout for `vary` variable, I suspect it would show no 32-bit alignment, meaning a large-ish array of these values would definitely be more space-efficient that `uint32_t`. But again, that's only for *one* environment, users of this info should check their own results.

Comment: @paxdiablo I understand your point and I agree that in certain circumstances your solution might be an effective way to save RAM especially for large arrays. However, I guess it might be helpful for the OP to take alignment in consideration as well.

Comment: What's the point of the `& 0xff` in packing, e.g. `retVal.byt[2] = x & 0xff;` ? Isn't the integral conversion done in assignment into the `uint8_t` doing exactly that?

Comment: @Jake1234, it may well do that, but the code here shows intent rather than action. Any non-brain-dead compiler would optimise it out anyway. It's the same reason I prefer the `x == 0` expression when checking for zero, to the simpler `! x`.

Comment: Thank you, I was just unsure whether perhaps it's actually not safe.

Answer (score 4):

[A comment by João Baptista](https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/06/three-byte-integers/#comment-508193) on [this site](https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/06/three-byte-integers/) says that you can use `#pragma pack`. Another option is to use `__attribute__((packed))`:

```
#ifndef __GNUC__
# define __attribute__(x)
#endif
struct uint24_t { unsigned long v:24; };
typedef struct uint24_t __attribute__((packed)) uint24_t;
```

This should work on GCC and Clang.

Note, however, that this will probably screw up alignment unless your processor supports unaligned access.

Comment: Packing / controlling padding is one consideration, but if you're using a bitfield then the size and number of its underlying storage unit(s) is a separate one, so packing does not necessarily have the effect you might expect here.  But I find that it *does* have that effect with GCC, so very nice.

Answer (score 2):

> Initially I thought it was because it is forcing datatypes to be word aligned

Different datatypes can have different alignment. See for example the [Objects and alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object) doc.

You can use `alignof` to check, but it's totally normal for `char` or `uint8_t` to have 1-byte (ie, effectively no) alignment, but for `uint32_t` to have 4-byte alignment. I don't know if the alignment of bitfields is explicitly described, but inheriting it from the storage type seems reasonable enough.

NB. The reason for having alignment requirements is generally that it works better with the underlying hardware. If you *do* use `#pragma pack` or `__attribute__((packed))` or whatever, you may take a performance hit as the compiler - or the memory hardware - silently handle misaligned accesses.

Just explicitly storing a 3-byte array is probably better, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, don't use bit-fields or structs. They may include padding as they please and bit-fields are non-portable in general.

Unless your CPU explicitly got 24 bit arithmetic instructions - which doesn't seem very likely unless it's some oddball DSP - then a custom data type will achieve nothing but extra stack bloat.

Most likely you will have to use `uint32_t` for all arithmetic. Meaning that your 24 bit type might not achieve much when it comes to saving RAM. If you invent some custom ADT with setter/getter (serialization/de-serialization) access, you are probably just *wasting* RAM since you get higher stack peak usage if the functions can't be inlined.

To actually save RAM you should rather revise your program design.

---

That being said, you can create a custom type based on an array:

```
typedef unsigned char u24_t[3];
```

Whenever you need to access the data, you `memcpy` it to/from a 32 bit type and then do all arithmetic on 32 bits:

```
u24_t    u24;
uint32_t u32;
...
memcpy(&u32, u24, sizeof(u24));
...
memcpy(&u24, &u32, sizeof(u24));
```

But note that this assumes little endian, since we are only working with bits 0 to 2. In case of a big endian system, you will have to do `memcpy((uint8_t*)&u32+1, ...` to discard the MS byte.