# C# - how to put 4 bit and 12 bit into 2 bytes

Tags: c#, byte

I have 2 `bytes` that should populate this way:

first number (4b)    second number (12b)

So 4 bit can be between 1-15
And 12 bit can be between 1-50

So i have this `Bytes Array`:

```
byte[] packetArrayBytes = new byte[Length];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67850144/is-there-a-10-bits-unsigned-integer-data-type-in-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define "custom" integer-based type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615113/define-custom-integer-based-type) and [How to create 24 bit unsigned integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010178/how-to-create-24-bit-unsigned-integer-in-c)

Comment: Do you mean: packetArrayBytes[0] = (byte)((someNumber >> 12) & 0xFF);
            packetArrayBytes[1] = (byte)((someNumber >> 4) & 0xFF); ?

Comment: I don't remember in detail this stuff that I haven't used for over 20 years, sorry. But indeed: you can use [bits masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) on one value, or you can use two values embedded in a type to control each min and max with get/set as well as for example calculations. It all depends on the level of complexity and abstraction or portability of the code and the performance you want to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've understood the question is that you've got these two (presumably) unsigned integers `a` and `b`:
(I'll be writing them in hexadecimal to make it easier to read)

`a: 0x0000000X`

`b: 0x00000XXX`

Where `a` is the 4-bit number and `b` is the 12-bit one, with the `X`s marking the bits containing the relevant values.

You want to store them in two separate 8-bit chunks: `c: 0x00` and `d: 0x00`

So you need to shift the bits into position, like this:

```cs
byte[] packetArrayBytes = new byte[2];

uint intA = 0xF;   // Allowed range is 0-15   (0x0-0xF)
uint intB = 0xABC; // Allowed range is 0-4095 (0x0-0xFFF)

// Need to convert from uint to bytes:
byte[] bytesA = BitConverter.GetBytes(intA);
byte[] bytesB = BitConverter.GetBytes(intB);
byte a = bytesA[0]; // a is 0x0F
byte b = bytesB[1]; // b is 0x0A
int c = 0x00;      // c is 0x00
int d = bytesB[0]; // d is 0xBC

// Mask out 4 least significant bits of a,
// then shift 4 bits left to place them in the most significant bits (of the byte),
// then OR them into c.
c |= (a & 0x0F) << 4;  // c is now 0xF0

// Mask out 4 least significant bits of b,
// then OR them into c.
c |= b & 0x0F;   // c is now 0xFA

packetArrayBytes[0] = (Byte)c;
packetArrayBytes[1] = (Byte)d;

Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(packetArrayBytes)); // Prints "FA-BC"
```

After doing these operations, the values of `a` and `b` should be placed in the bytes `c` and `d` like this:
`c: 0xFA` `d: 0xBC`. Which you can then place into your array.

To get the values back you just do these same operations in reverse.

If `a` and `b` are signed values, I believe the same operations work, but you'll have to make sure you're not interpreting them as unsigned when reading the data back into numbers.

Comment: and how to put this into my array ?

Comment: `c` and `d` are the two bytes you want in the array so you should just be able to do `packetArrayBytes[0] = c;` and `packetArrayBytes[1] = d;`

Comment: OK than ks a lot, I will try it now and update

Comment: In the last 3 lines (c |= (a & 0x0F) << 4; & c |= (b & 0xF00) >> 8; & d |= b & 0x0FF;) i got this compiler error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'byte'.

Comment: Ah right, this isn't C++ it's C#. My bad. You'll need to convert the `uint`s to bytes first using [BitConverter.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-5.0)

Comment: What about change byte c into uint c and then: arrayBytes[0] = (byte)a; ?

Comment: I've updated my solution, try that instead.

Comment: Almost same issue: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. here: c |= (a & 0x0F) << 4; and here: c |= b & 0x0F;

Comment: Apparently C# does not have bitwise operators defined for `byte` so it implicitly converts them to `int`. A bit strange IMO, but easily remedied by changing a couple of the variables from `byte` to `int`. I've now tested the code myself and it runs and produces the correct output.

Comment: For more info about these operators, I found the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079986/why-do-cs-binary-operators-always-return-int-regardless-of-the-format-of-their) helpful.

Comment: So in the last example what 2 numbers you choose ? 15 and 2748 ?

Comment: Yes, `0xF = 15` and `0xABC = 2748`.